# How to define an entity property, in GAE datastore, to be unique?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can I set property to be unique in GAE?

For example If I have

```
Entity person1 = new Entity ("Person");
person.setProperty("name","Adelin"); // I want to define this as Unique ! No Duplication !

Entity person2 = new Entity ("Person");
person.setProperty("name","Adelin");


datastore.save(person1);
datastore.save(person2); // I want here to throw some exception !!
```

I want the answer in Java

Comment: Have you considered using the unique property value as the key name.  It is much easier to acheive uniqueness this way.

Comment: @Adio Keep in mind that if you use the the value as the key name you won't be able to renamed that if you have to..

Comment: Tim Hoffman May you clarify your point. I was thinking that I understand you but obviously I don't !

Comment: `Adelin` is not unique

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in Java but here is a Python solution you can probably port easily:
http://squeeville.com/2009/01/30/add-a-unique-constraint-to-google-app-engine/

I use this technique in multiple applications.

Comment: If you follow that example, you'll need to run the uniqueness check and the new entity creation in a transaction, or else it's still possible for a race condition to create multiple entities with the same property.